# How can I clobber factory girl associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have this factory generated:

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :account_login do |n|
      "login-#{ n }"
    end



  factory :account do
    sequence :email do |n|
      "someone#{n}@gmail.com"
    end
    email_confirmation { |account| account.send :email }
    url { Faker::Internet.url }
    login { generate(:account_login) }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    password_confirmation { |account| account.send(:password) }
    current_password { |account| account.send(:password) }
    twitter_account 'openhub'
    name { Faker::Name.name + rand(999_999).to_s }
    about_raw { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
    activated_at { Time.current }
    activation_code nil
    country_code 'us'
    email_master true
    email_kudos true
    email_posts true
    association :github_verification
  end
 end
```

What I really need to do is to create a second factory that creates a user with a nil github_verification attribute.

Something like this:

```
factory :account_with_no_verifications, parent: :account do
  associaton github_verification = nil
end
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: is `github_verification` an `belongs_to` association? then try: `github_verification_id nil`

Comment: not quite, its a has_one association, so an account has one github_verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `FactoryGirl::Strategy::Null` http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/FactoryGirl/Strategy/Null

```
factory :account_with_no_verifications, parent: :account do
  association github_verification, strategy: :null
end
```